# How can I convert a char to int in Java?

Tags: java, char, type-conversion, int

(I'm new at Java programming)

I have for example:

```
char x = '9';
```

and I need to get the number in the apostrophes, the digit 9 itself.
I tried to do the following,

```
char x = 9;
int y = (int)(x);
```

but it didn't work.

So what should I do to get the digit in the apostrophes?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

The ASCII table is arranged so that the value of the character `'9'` is nine greater than the value of `'0'`; the value of the character `'8'` is eight greater than the value of `'0'`; and so on.

So you can get the int value of a decimal digit char by subtracting `'0'`.

```
char x = '9';
int y = x - '0'; // gives the int value 9
```

Comment: @HaimLvov: To elaborate... Take a look at the ASCII table anywhere online.  Any `char` has the numeric value of its equivalent decimal value in that table.  So you can subtract any one from any other to get a numeric result.  It just so happens, naturally, that the characters 0 through 9 are in order so the math works.

Comment: more about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195028/please-explain-what-this-code-is-doing-somechar-48

Comment: @David - Is this answer better than Character.getNumericValue(x) in terms of performance ?

Comment: In ASCII '0' = 48, 1='49' etc. Found a helpful explanation about the theory here: https://beginnersbook.com/2019/04/java-char-to-int-conversion/

Comment: A nice ASCII table can be found here : https://www.alpharithms.com/ascii-table-512119/

Answer (score 63):

I you have the `char '9'`, it will store its ASCII code, so to get the int value, you have 2 ways

```
char x = '9';
int y = Character.getNumericValue(x);   //use a existing function
System.out.println(y + " " + (y + 1));  // 9  10
```

or

```
char x = '9';
int y = x - '0';                        // substract '0' code to get the difference
System.out.println(y + " " + (y + 1));  // 9  10
```

---

And it fact, this works also :

```
char x = 9;
System.out.println(">" + x + "<");     //>  < prints a horizontal tab
int y = (int) x;
System.out.println(y + " " + (y + 1)); //9 10
```

You store the `9` code, which corresponds to a `horizontal tab` (you can see when print as `String`, bu you can also use it as `int` as you see above

Answer (score 28):

You can use static methods from Character class to get Numeric value from char.

```
char x = '9';

if (Character.isDigit(x)) { // Determines if the specified character is a digit.
    int y = Character.getNumericValue(x); //Returns the int value that the 
                                          //specified Unicode character represents.
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the ASCII value of a character, or just convert it into an int, you need to cast from a char to an int.

What's casting? Casting is when we explicitly convert from one primitve data type, or a class, to another. Here's a brief example.

```
public class char_to_int
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
       char myChar = 'a';
       int  i = (int) myChar; // cast from a char to an int
       System.out.println ("ASCII value - " + i);
  }
```

In this example, we have a character ('a'), and we cast it to an integer. Printing this integer out will give us the ASCII value of 'a'.

Comment: OP doesn't want to get the ASCII value, he wants to get the value when interpreting this character as an actual number. For '9' he wants to return 9 rather than 57 (the ASCII value of '9')