# how can an int method return char

Tags: java, function, methods, types, return

i have a method with signature int but the compiler hints me to return c which is type char.

1/ how is it possible to return char variable in this case

//scissors , paper , rock are static final in gamelogic class

```
public int getInput(){  
    String choice;
    char c;
    do {
        System.out.println("Make a choice");
        choice  = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        c = choice.charAt(0);

        if(c == 'P'){
            return gameLogic.paper;
        }else if(c == 'R'){
            return gameLogic.rock;
        }else if(c== 'S'){
            return gameLogic.scissor;
        }
    }while(c != 'S' && c != 'R' && c != 'P');
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a char to int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343616/how-can-i-convert-a-char-to-int-in-java)

Comment: Please use the search engine next time ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343616/how-can-i-convert-a-char-to-int-in-java/46343671

Comment: it's not the same point!

Comment: Same reason you can write `public double foo() {return 1;}`.

Comment: @AKSW: That question has nothing to do with this one. At best, the title sounds like it could be related, but the actual content is completely unrelated.

Comment: `public char getInput()`

Comment: **Unrelated:** Your `while` statement will always be `true` (because it is only reached if P, R, and S are not selected). Perhaps you mean to `return c;` as the final `else` of your `if` statement?

Comment: But to answer your question, a `char` is really just a pointer to a character's location in an ASCII table, which is an integer. For example, the `char` "k" is ASCII #75. So if the user were to type "k," the method would return `75`.

Comment: **Unrelated 1:** Java naming convention is for class names to start with uppercase letter, and for constants (`static final` fields) to be all uppercase, so your code should be `return GameLogic.PAPER;`. --- **Unrelated 2:** This is a great example of code that should use an `enum`. You should have a `HandShape` enum type with `ROCK`, `PAPER`, and `SCISSOR` as enum values, and your methods return type should be `HandShape` using `null` for the final `return` statement, or the return type should be `Optional<HandShape>`, using `Optional.empty()` for the final `return` statement.

Comment: @Zephyr Please watch your terminology. It is the character *code*, or maybe the *index*, for a character set. It is certainly not a *pointer*, since that term has other meanings.

Comment: @Andreas - Just trying to explain it in layman's terms. I missed the chance to edit my comment by a couple of seconds, but you are correct, it is a "code or index that indicate's a character's location in the character set."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char` is really just an unsigned 16-bit integer.  An `int` is a 32-bit integer.  Therefore, every `char` value will fit in an `int`, with no loss of information.

This known as a *widening primitive conversion.* From [the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> A widening conversion of a `char` to an integral type T zero-extends the representation of the `char` value to fill the wider format.

In your case, the “integral type T” is `int`.

Answer (score -1):

changed `return c;` to `return Character.getNumericValue(c);`

```
public int getInput(){  
    String choice;
    char c;
    do {
        System.out.println("Make a choice");
        choice  = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        c = choice.charAt(0);

        if(c == 'P'){
            return gameLogic.paper;
        }else if(c == 'R'){
            return gameLogic.rock;
        }else if(c== 'S'){
            return gameLogic.scissor;
        }
    }while(c != 'S' && c != 'R' && c != 'P');
    return Character.getNumericValue(c);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can return char value and it will be automatically converted to int by java. compiler would indicate to return a value at the end as all the returns are based on condition