# Integer.valueOf returns ASCII against a character

Tags: java, integer, character

`Integer.valueOf` takes in `String` and `int` as arguments but when I pass `Character`, it doesn't require casting and compiler doesn't enforce anything.

Character doesn't extend `String` class, it just implements `Serializable` and `Comparable`

```
Character charc = '1';
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(charc));
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(charc.toString()));
```

output:

```
49
1
```

Isn't it kind of design flaw or I am thinking in the wrong direction?
Please write the reason in comments when you down-vote it.

[image]

Comment: char can be autoboxed to an int

Comment: @AndyTurner posted screenshot..

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo consider `Character charc = '1';
  int i = charc;
  System.out.println(i);`  - same result

Comment: @ScaryWombat that will print 1 instead of 49 ... it prints 49

Comment: No - it prints 49

Comment: @ScaryWombat  `Character charc = '1'; System.out.println(charc); ` prints 1. I am on compiler now.

Comment: That is not my code - read carefully  `Character -> char -> int`

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343616/how-can-i-convert-a-char-to-int-in-java/46343671

Comment: @ScaryWombat got it.. so basically it's converting the Character to char and then it auto converts it into `int` which is why it prints 49

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `char` ist auto-widened to an int, which is a perfectly valid parameter for `Integer.valueOf()`

Java converts some types automatically if the required type contains all of the current type like char to int or int to long. See the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) for details.

Answer (score 5):

This is specifically covered by [JLS 5.2, Assignment conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2). (Passing a parameter to a method is essentially like assigning a value to a variable.)

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> ...
>
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

What's happening here is that the `Character` is being unboxed to `char`; and then the `char` is being widened to `int`.