# How to convert a string to an integer in C programming language, based on this strict example?

Tags: c, integer

Example:

```
// variable fixed
Char specialstring[PATH_MAX];
int integernumber;
int xx = 1 ; 
int yy = 1 ; 
strncopy( specialstring, "1369", ... bla); 


// here we go !! help there below please
integernumber=atoi(specialstring);
mvprintw( yy , xx , "%d" , integernumber );
```

Please help me in the way to convert the specialstring to an integer?

thank you

Comment: `atoi` already converts the string(`specialstring`) to a number(`integernumber`), what exactly is your question? You want this conversion without using `atoi`?

Comment: What's wrong with `atoi`? What's in `specialstring`?

Comment: this should be okay, what is the output?

Comment: [blog]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781668/char-to-int-conversion-in-c/ " check this answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you have two mistakes:

**1)**  `strncopy` is not the function you wants its `strncpy`.  its man page: 
[char *strncpy(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2, size_t n);](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncpy.html)
Here `s1` is destination string and `s2` is source string , `n` is number of chars you wants to copy from source.

So correct:

```
strncopy( specialstring, "1369", ... bla); 
     ^                            ^ should be `n` num of chars you wants to 
    strncpy                         copy in `specialstring`
```

into

```
 strncpy( specialstring, "1369", 4);
```

**2)** In declaration of `specialstring`,  `Char` is wrong you should write small `c`

```
Char specialstring[PATH_MAX];
^ small letter

char  specialstring[PATH_MAX];
```

**3)** `atoi()`  is correct function you got to convert a string into int, if you wants to convert without `atoi` you can use `sscanf()` function like:

```
sscanf(specialstring,"%d", &integernumber);
```

View this: [**Working Code**](http://codepad.org/cHjItkJC)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to convert string to int without using atoi

```
int Convert(char * str)
{
    int result =0;
int len=strlen(str);
for(int i=0,j=len-1;i<len;i++,j--)
    {
    result += ((int)str[i] - 48)*pow(10,j);
    }

   return result;
}
```

Comment: -1. This assumes ASCII. The implementation of `atoi` on a given platform may take into consideration the fact that it uses another form of storing characters, which is why it should be used instead. Also, `pow` operates on floating-point values, which is simply unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Sorry...but can you explain more...and isn't this a valid code for converting string to integer??

Comment: It is valid if the platform where that code is used uses ASCII and if you, as a programmer, don't mind having unnecessary operations in your code.

Comment: Not to mention that it does not support signed numbers, which are properly converted by `atoi`.