# Why use '\0' instead of 0 for memset?

Tags: c++, c

According to the this Unix documentation http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bzero.html

```
The memset() function is preferred over bzero().

For maximum portability, it is recommended to replace 
the function call to bzero() as follows:

#define bzero(b,len) (memset((b), '\0', (len)), (void) 0)
```

But `void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);` second arg is an **int** so why are they recommending '\0' instead of 0? The memset() doc says "The memset() function shall copy **c** (***converted to an unsigned char***) arg into each of the first **n** bytes of the object pointed to by **s**." Is this more efficient or simply more explicit? Is there a best practice involved here?

Comment: In C, `'\0'` is an `int`. However, it shouldn't matter which you use.

Comment: `bzero()` isn't standard, never use it

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I have to say that I've wondered about this too. Personally I would go with trying to be explicit. (I am not aware of any possible problems with converting `0` -> `'\0'`)

Comment: @KasiyA `'\0'` is not a `char`.  It is an `int`.

Comment: @KasiyA : You're wrong. Character literals are ints.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Assuming C, but this is also tagged C++... (on a side note, how did `char` literal end up being an `int` in C?)

Comment: `'\0'` and `0` are both the same constant.  Use is a style choice.  If the target of `memset()` is a `char *`, IMO, `'\0'` conveys more meaning.  Else use `0`.

Comment: @chux :: this is tagged `c++`; in C++, `'\0'` is not `int`, it's `char`.

Comment: @Massa. I said this to chux, Daniel Kamil Kozar but he said it's wrong.Please delete your wrong post that post for me.

Comment: @Massa Agree in C++ `'\0'` is `char` and in C it is `int`.  Post is tagged both C & C++.

Comment: Nips, just looked around for like 10 seconds, this question has about a million dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919735/why-does-memset-take-an-int-instead-of-a-char http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781668/char-to-int-conversion-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096990/why-use-bzero-over-memset

Comment: For those who have enough rep to see deleted answers, the constant `0` always has type `int`. Octal constants (yes, `0` is octal) can have any of several integer types depending on their values and the ranges of the predefined integer types. `0`, because of its value, can never be anything but `int`.

Comment: Nips indeed! The question may be answered but it is not a duplicate. I did not ask why use bzero over memset - not a dupe. I did not ask how to convert a char to an int - not a dupe. I did not ask why does memset take an int - not a dupe. Your definition of dupe is ludicrous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> second arg is an int so why are they recommending '\0' instead of 0?

To make it clear the thing is going to end up as a NUL character; after all `memset` will convert it to `unsigned char`. This is just a matter of style, because `'\0'` has type `int` and is thus the same as `0`.

Comment: In C++, any *conforming* compiler, sane or otherwise, will convert `'\0'` to `0` at compile time. In C, no conversion occurs because `'\0'` is already of type `int`.

Comment: character literals in c are ints anyway, not chars. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars

Comment: The question is tagged both C and C++. In C, `'\0'` has type `int`. In C++, it has type `char`. (In either case, passing `'\0'` as the second argument of `memset` is perfectly correct.)

Answer (score 4):

Is it more efficient?

In a way: `bzero` was never actually part of the standard. That's why the page you link to recommends using `memset`. So using `memset` is more efficient in the sense that you can rest assured that your code compiles on *all* standard C compilers.

*`'\0'` instead of `0`*
The standard requires that a char can be safely converted to an int:

> Both the basic source and basic execution character sets shall have the following
>   members:
>   [...]
>   the 10 decimal *digits*
>          `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
>   [...]
>   In both the source and execution basic character sets, the
>   value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than
>   the value of the previous.

So passing `'\0'` to an int param is not a problem. What's more: you are passing a *zero-escape-sequence*, which is actually the same as passing 0.
It is, however, more explicit: `memset` will initialize N bytes to whatever value you pass to it. The only type in C that is *guaranteed* to be 1 and only 1 byte big, is the `char` type.

So:

```
memset(some_ptr, 0, 12);
//is, in practice identical to:
memset(some_ptr, '\0', 12);
```

But seeing as you're setting 12 bytes, passing a value of a 1-byte-big type better reflects this. I prefer passing a char explicitly for that reason, but it's up to you.

*History of `memset`:*
The function `memset` has been around for ages. In fact, it existed back in the days the function prototypes!

Another thing to keep in mind is how character literals in C, by themselves, are, like most any literal value, ints.

Comment: +1 for a complete answer;  Unclear about wording in "it existed back in the days the function prototypes".

Comment: `\0` is not a digit, so your quote is irrelevant.

Comment: "In a way: `bzero` was never actually part of the standard." What do you mean by "in a way"? `bzero` was never part of any official C or C++ standard; that's unambiguous.

Comment: @KeithThompson: `bzero` is standardized by POSIX.

Comment: @larsmans: Actually, it isn't. `bzero` was deprecated and marked as LEGACY by POSIX.1-2001, and removed entirely by POSIX-1.2008. You make a good point that it *was* specified by *a* standard, but at least in my experience the phrase "the standard" usually refers to the ANSI or ISO language standard.

Comment: @KeithThompson Sure, except when the OP is citing POSIX :)

Comment: @KeithThompson: I meant _"in a way"_ as in: `memset` is more efficient, because it's standard. Writing C code means writing portable code. `bzero` isn't standard, so your code won't be as portable, so for your code to be portable, it'd require you to define a `bzero` macro that expands to a `memset` call, which is silly, and makes your code less maintainable, hence: coding will be less efficient. But either way, I think I'll delete this answer later on

Comment: I read it as "In a way," rather than "In a way:"; the colon vs. the comma I *thought* I saw there changes the meaning. Sorry for any confusion.