# Given a string consisting of alphabets and digits, find the frequency of each digit in the given string

Tags: c, frequency, digits

Please tell me whats wrong in code the output is 00000000.
I know there is some mistake but cant find it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
     int c=0;
     char s[100];
     fgets(s, 100, stdin);
     printf("%s", s);
     for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
     {
         for(int j=0;j<strlen(s);j++)
         {
             if(s[j]==i){
                 c++;
            }           
         }
         printf("%d", c);
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are comparing a character with a int. Have a look at [Char to int conversion in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781668/char-to-int-conversion-in-c) for a solution.

Then, I would remember you that "0" is index 48 in ASCII table, not 0 : http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: I wouldn't bother to use the value `48`.   All real-world character sets (including those the subject of standards) have the digits in a contiguous set starting with `0` and increasing.  So  subtracting `'0'` from any digit extracts the numerical equivalent  (`'0' - '0'` - > `0`,  `'1' - '0'` -> `1`, .... `'9' - '0'` -> `9`).

Comment: This is also a requirement in the C standard for compliant execution character sets.

Answer (score 0):

The key problem is `s[j]==i`. That compares a `char` of the string to the values 0 to 9 ratter than to `char` `'0'` to `'9'`.

Another is the `c` is not reset to zero each loop.

---

Instead of looping 10 times, test if the `char` is a digit.

Instead of calling `j<strlen(s)` repeatedly, just test if `s[j] == 0`

```
 size_t digit_frequency[10] = {0};

 for (size_t i=0; s[i]; i++) {
   if (isdigit((unsigned char) s[i])) {
   // or  if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
     digit_frequency[s[i] - '0']++;
   }
 }

 for (size_t i=0; i<10; i++) {
   pritnf("%zu\n", s[i]);
 }
```

---

Code uses `size_t` rather than `int` as a *string*'s length is limited to `size_t` - which may exceed `int` in extreme cases.  Either work OK work size 100.

`isdigit()` declared in `<ctype.h>`

`(unsigned char)` used as `isdigit()` expect a value in the `(unsigned char)` and `EOF` and a `char` may be negative.

Various style choices - all function the same.

```
for (size_t i=0; s[i]; i++) {
for (size_t i=0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
for (size_t i=0; s[i] != 0; i++) {
```

"Given a string consisting of alphabets and digits" is a minor contraction.  In C, a *string* includes the final *null character*: "A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character"  C11 §7.1.1 1.  Yet folks often speak colloquially as is the *null character* was not part of the string.

Comment: Another style choice for the loop: `for (char *t = s; *t; ++t)`.   Then use `*t` in the loop body in places where you use `s[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

you did wrong in this line "if(s[j]==i)" and you didn't create any separate array for storing for frequency of digits and if you are using a single variable for frequency counting then it will show the cumulative of strings frequency

you can take is code as a reference

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *s;
    s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", s);
    s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);
    int len = strlen(s), i;
    int arr[10];
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        arr[i] = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
            arr[(int)(s[i] - '0')]++;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_LEN 1000

int main() {
    char s[MAX_LEN];
    char num[10]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    int arr[10] = {0};
    scanf("%s",s);
    for (int i =0; i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=9;j++)
        {
            if (s[i] == num[j])
            {
                arr[j]+=1;
            }

        }
    }
    for (int j =0;j<=9;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[j]);       
    }
        
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).